# OpenShift 4.3.3, keep getting root error with containers

Tags: docker, kubernetes, containers, openshift

I just downloaded OpenShift 4.3.3 and trying out the free trial. I am getting a root problem when I try to run containers in OpenShift.

```
Warning alert:Image runs as root
Image alpine runs as the root user which might not be permitted by your cluster administrator.
```

If I try running this container anyways, it alternates between Completed and CrashLoopBackOff error. The funny thing is, I am the only user and I have admin privileges on my account. I found a solution for OpenShift 3 where I run `oc login -u system:admin` and it will ask me for a password before telling me:

`error: username system:admin is invalid for basic auth`

To recreate: Developer view -> Add -> Container Image -> Image name = alpine -> defaults for everything else -> Create

Answer (score 0):

By default, Openshift runs containers as a non-root user. It looks like your image requires you to run it as root. You should update the security context permissions of the user and namespace.
e.g.

```
oc adm policy add-scc-to-user privileged -z default -n <YOUR_NAMESPACE>
```

Comment: I tried your command and got this response:
```
Error from server (Forbidden): securitycontextconstraints.security.openshift.io "privileged" is forbidden: User "hustlin" cannot get resource "securitycontextconstraints" in API group "security.openshift.io" at the cluster scope
```

Comment: You should run this with your cluster admin context.

Comment: Sorry, I am new to OpenShift. How do I run this in the cluster admin context?